# Comparing baseline differences including file contents

Tags: diff, clearcase, baseline

I know that I can use the diffbl command to compare two baselines. But how can I also ask the command to print out the diffs of all the files that were different?

Is this even possible or do I need to write a script or something? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get with cleartool alone is [`cleartool diffbl -ver`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm)

For each version, you can make a [`cleartool diff -dif -pred <aversion>`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-10) in order to print the actual diff (using the [`-dif` format](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-10), where differences are reported in the style of the UNIX and Linux `diff` utility)

As mentioned in the comments, the `diff -pred` only prints the diff introduced by a specific version.
**The concatenation of all those diffs represents all the modifications introduced by the new baseline compared to the old one**.
In other word, that concatenation of diffs represents "print out the diffs of all the files that were different". What was originally asked for.

Comment: diffbl -ver returns a list of versions of elements. There may be more than one version of the same element. So what does the "ct diff -dif -pred <version>" really do? does it print the diff between the two versions of this element from the two baselines?

Comment: @shikhanshu no, the diff -pred only print the diff introduced by that specifc version. The concatenation of all those diffs represents all the modifications introduced by the new baseline compared to the old one. In other word, that concatenation of diffs represents "print out the diffs of all the files that were different". What you were asking for.